# Save & load best model in AutoTS python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, forecasting

After fitting AutoTS model over some time series data, how can I save & load the best model trained? Though, the AutoTS object has export_template() & import_template() functions to save best model, but while loading best model from this template, it requires re-fitting. How can such a solution be used in production? My code:

```
from autots import AutoTS

model = AutoTS(
frequency='infer',
prediction_interval=0.9,
ensemble=None,
model_list="fast",  # "superfast", "default", "fast_parallel"
transformer_list="fast",  # "superfast",
drop_most_recent=1,
max_generations=4,
num_validations=2,
validation_method="backwards") 

 model.fit(df_day,date_col='xyz',value_col='abc')
 model.export_template("unique_user_1", models='best', n=1, max_per_model_class=3)
```

Now, in some new instance, when I do

```
 model = model.import_template('unique_user_1.csv',method='only')
```

The model required retraining.

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with your code is that you have named your export_template as 'unique_user_1' without an extension. Try saving it as csv file with 'unique_user_1.csv'

Once you feel you are done with training your model. Write the following lines

```py
model.export_template(
    "unique_user_1.csv",
    models="best",
    max_per_model_class=1,
    include_results=True
)
```

To load the template & reuse it

```py
model = model.import_template(
    "unique_user_1.csv",
    method="only",
    enforce_model_list=True)

model.fit(data)

prediction = model.predict(forecast_length=15)
```